# How do I do something after Maven copies the webapp resources during the `package` goal?

Tags: java, maven, build, war, lifecycle

How do I do something after Maven copies the webapp resources to the war directory inside of the `package` goal? I want to do something just after it copies the webapp resources to the target's war directory, but just before it finally archives everything into a WAR file.

Answer (score 9):

The reason you're having problems is because the copying of webapp resources is done by the [war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) in the same breath that it builds the war. It's not a different lifecycle phase or even two different actions in the same phase. It's all part of the [war:war goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html).

There's a workaround, though. If you bind [war:exploded](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html) to an earlier phase, like `prepare-package`, then it will build your exploded webapp, and then you can put something after that to modify the files that were built to the exploded directory. Then `war:war` will package up the modified exploded directory. (With newer versions of the war plugin, I believe you'll need to set the [`useCache`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#useCache) property to get the desired behavior, though that doesn't seem to really be what it's for, be wary.)

Comment: Thank you! I will totally try this out. I've asked this question on maven mailing list and on tons of places, and everyone tells me what the below poster said... which I tried 2+ days ago :( Your answer is a sign of hope! It's something I haven't heard before! Thank you!

Comment: would it possible to give an example on how to bind to earlier phase?

Comment: Please Ryan, can you answer this? I'd love to give you the checkmark, but I don't know what you mean by this and I googled this phrase and come up with nothing.

Comment: Declare a plugin in your pom, give it an execution, and set the "phase" element to the appropriate lifecycle phase. See ["The Build Lifecycle"](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-structure.html) in the Sonatype book for information about how builds really work in Maven.

Comment: So are you saying to assign the `maven-war-plugin` to a different phase? I think I understand how to assign war:exploded to a different phase. The thing is, I actually have tried moving the phases of things, so I know how to do it actually. But I'm not sure how to do this for `war:exploded` as you suggested.

Answer (score 7):

I've just had to do the same thing so here's an example for egervari to show what Ryan Stewart is saying.

(This uses the YUI Compressor Maven Mojo to automatically minify js files.)

```
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>${warName}</warName>
                        <useCache>true</useCache>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exploded</goal>
                            </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compress</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>           
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this doesn't work for me, the yui compress process does start after the web sources are copied, but then overwritten again by war:war goal. my solution is:       <configuration>
<warSourceExcludes>**/dojo/**,**/*.css</warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>

Comment: Thank you for example, with little modification it works. I get exception `Cannot construct org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructure as it does not have a no-args constructor` but upgrading maven-war-plugin to 2.4 helps

Answer (score -1):

As documented in the build [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

> **prepare-package**   perform any operations necessary to prepare a package
>   before the actual packaging. This often results in an unpacked,
>   processed version of the package. (Maven 2.1 and above)
>
> **package**   take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as
>   a JAR.

You would want to bind your goal which does something to one of these goals, depending on how your pom executes.

I haven't tried this and hence can't say which one with authority.

Comment: I have tried this, and pre-package occurs before the webapp resources are copied, while package occurs after the war archive has been created, thus it is too late. There is no phase that is after the copying of the resources but before the war file is made.